# how to pass object as parameter in Flutter post api call using Retrofit?

Tags: json, flutter, object, authentication, retrofit

I want to send login details(email,password,deviceId) as login parameter as a object when calling login api using retrofit in flutter.

I am using this tutorial : http://www.androidcoding.in/2020/08/13/flutter-retrofit-post/

@POST("/tasks") Future createTask(@Body() Task task);

like in body (@Body() Task task).

but unable to send parameter in api as a object. How to do this? Please help or any example regarding this

Comment: what did you mean as Object?

Comment: @POST("/tasks")
  Future<Task> createTask(@Body() Task task);                  I want send parameter in body as here. Hope it is understandable.

Comment: Are you use @JsonSerializable() in top of your model class?

Comment: Yes, i am using.

Comment: Did you find a solution?