# Could not find method implementation() for arguments in Flutter

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

When I try to integrating FireBase to my Flutter project, I'm getting the following error:

> "Could not find method implementation() for arguments
> [com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3] on object of type
> org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler".

File `pubspec.yaml`:

```
version: 1.0.0+1
environment:
   sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
   flutter:
     sdk: flutter
  firebase_analytics: ^5.0.2
  firebase_core: ^0.4.0+9
  cloud_firestore: ^0.12.9+5`enter code here`
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3

  dev_dependencies:
     flutter_test:
       sdk: flutter
```

App build gradle (`app\build.gradle`):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
        lintOptions {
            disable 'InvalidPackage'
        }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.flutter_demo_app"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

buildscript {
   dependencies {
       implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
   }
}
```

Why this error is happening?

Comment: add your build.gradle and pubspec.yaml file

Comment: build.gradle and pubspect.yaml added.

Comment: check my answer

Comment: @Peter Haddar    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63994019/how-to-pass-object-as-parameter-in-flutter-post-api-call-using-retrofit         can you help me in this question

Comment: I have not used retrofit in flutter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update both `firebase_core` and `cloud_firestore` to the latest version:

```
firebase_core: ^0.5.0
cloud_firestore: ^0.14.0+2
```

And inside `build.gradle` file upgrade the `minSdkVersion` to the following:

```
minSdkVersion 23
```

after performing the above actions, you need to remove the following line:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
```

Comment: giving same problem after trying your answer.

Comment: close the ide and remove the app, then open the ide again and try flutter run

Comment: which flutter version do you have?

Comment: Flutter 1.20.4     ,    • Dart 2.9.2

Comment: did you add google-services classpath to the other build.gradle file and which version?

Comment: classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'

Comment: remove "implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63994019/how-to-pass-object-as-parameter-in-flutter-post-api-call-using-retrofit        Hi Peter, can you help me in this problem? @ Peter Haddad